# Need to set validation only 6 levels can be added of sub nodes in tree

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to restrict the user, so they can only add maximum 6 levels of sub-nodes. Currently they can add however many they want.

[image]

```js
// Add Child
function AddChild(element) {
  var ul = element.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  domString = '<div class="textbox_cls"> \n\
                                <span class="caret"></span>\n\
                                <span class="remove_user" parent_id="1">-</span>\n\
                                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Element">\n\
                                <span class="add_user" parent_id="1" onclick="AddChild(this);">+</span>\n\
                                <span class="drag_user">::</span>\n\
                            </div><ul></ul>';
  li.innerHTML = domString;
  ul.appendChild(li);

}
```

```css
input[type='text'] {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  color: gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.add_user {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 4px 0px 4px 5px;
}

.remove_user {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 20px !important;
  margin: 4px 5px 4px 0px;
}

.add_user,
.remove_user {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.drag_user {
  color: lightgrey;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  margin: 0px 5px;
}

.add_user,
.remove_user {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.User_listing ul {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.User_listing ul .textbox_cls {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
}

.add_user,
.remove_user,
.drag_user {
  cursor: move;
}

.User_listing>ul ul {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.User_listing>ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #369;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-left: 2px dashed rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.User_listing>ul li:last-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.User_listing>ul li:before {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 33px;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed rgb(0, 0, 0);
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0px;
}

.User_listing>ul li:last-child:before {
  border-left: 2px dashed rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="User_listing">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="textbox_cls" total_ul="1">
          <span class="caret"></span>
          <span class="remove_user" parent_id="1">-</span>
          <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Element" />
          <span class="add_user" parent_id="1" onclick="AddChild(this);">+</span>
          <span class="drag_user">::</span>
        </div>
        <ul> </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `span` that defines your  `+` I added a custom attribute - `level` and first set it to `1`. Then, in `AddChild` I'm getting this attribute using `getAttribute`, parsing it to int and increment it. Then pass the same attribute again in `domString`.

Each time the user is trying to add a child, I'm checking if the nesting level is max 6.

```js
// Add Child
function AddChild(element) {
  var ul = element.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var level = parseInt(element.getAttribute("level")) + 1;
  if (level <= 6) {
    domString = '<div class="textbox_cls"> \n\
                                <span class="caret"></span>\n\
                                <span class="remove_user" parent_id="1">-</span>\n\
                                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Element">\n\
                                <span class="add_user" level=' + level + ' parent_id="1" onclick="AddChild(this);">+</span>\n\
                                <span class="drag_user">::</span>\n\
                            </div><ul></ul>';
    li.innerHTML = domString;
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
}
```

```css
input[type='text'] {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  color: gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.add_user {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 4px 0px 4px 5px;
}

.remove_user {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 20px !important;
  margin: 4px 5px 4px 0px;
}

.add_user,
.remove_user {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.drag_user {
  color: lightgrey;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  margin: 0px 5px;
}

.add_user,
.remove_user {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.User_listing ul {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.User_listing ul .textbox_cls {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
}

.add_user,
.remove_user,
.drag_user {
  cursor: move;
}

.User_listing>ul ul {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.User_listing>ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #369;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-left: 2px dashed rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.User_listing>ul li:last-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.User_listing>ul li:before {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 33px;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed rgb(0, 0, 0);
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0px;
}

.User_listing>ul li:last-child:before {
  border-left: 2px dashed rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="User_listing">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="textbox_cls" total_ul="1">
          <span class="caret"></span>
          <span class="remove_user" parent_id="1">-</span>
          <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Element" />
          <span class="add_user" level=1 parent_id="1" onclick="AddChild(this);">+</span>
          <span class="drag_user">::</span>
        </div>
        <ul> </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```